# JAXB Unmarshall exception - unexpected element

Tags: exception, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have used a .xsd file to generate Java classes, and with an XML file, I need to unmarshall.

I am using this code :

```
JAXBContext objJAXBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("my.test");

// create an Unmarshaller
Unmarshaller objUnmarshaller = objJAXBContext.createUnmarshaller();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.xml");

JAXBElement<Root> objMyRoot = (JAXBElement<Root>) objUnmarshaller.unmarshal(fis);

Root mRoot = objMyRoot.getValue();
```

and I am getting this error:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Root"). Expected elements are (none)
```

I have seen many solutions but nothing works in my project.

What i can try to do?

Comment: You can start by showing us the contents of `test.xml`.

Answer (score 16):

Your xml root is missing the namespace (uri) attribute.
You better try this on the `XMLRootElement` ...

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root", namespace="")
```

Comment: namespace="" was critical for me

Comment: you mean changing auto-generated Java class and add this annotation to it?

Comment: If it takes to change generated code, why not.. I mean it can be buggy...

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource("test.xml")
JAXBElement<Root> objMyRoot = (JAXBElement<Root>) objUnmarshaller.unmarshal(streamsource, Root.class);
```

Comment: Can I use it with XML string?

Comment: @Line StreamSource only accepts InputStream, Reader and File sources. But you can use a `StringReader` to plug in your XML string.
`StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlText));`